# How to access an Orchard multi-tenant site externally on the same network

Tags: windows, iis, orchardcms, multi-tenant

I've got multi tenancy set up on my Windows 7 machine using Orchard 7.1 and IIS 6.1 which I can access locally no problem.

They relevant sites are all added within the bindings of the applicationhost.config file, as well as the computers' host file and therefore show up as they should by accessing the url.

I have previously had a single tenant set up on my machine that meant I could access on my network, which was done by adding the site to IIS then binding to localhost/my ip address etc.

However the issue I am having is how to access these sites via a mobile device/another computer (on the same network) now that I have set it up for multiple tenants.

Any help appreciated

Liam

Answer (score 0):

You'd need some sort of naming service inside your network, something like Bonjour.

Short of that, I guess you'd have to configure those other machines one by one so their hosts files point to the server.

One final possible possibility may be to simply use DNS. There is no reason why you couldn't use a domain that you control to map several names to local addresses such as that of your server.